# Are there any actual examples of "awful things happening to wizards who meddle with time" in the book?

Tags: harry-potter, time-travel

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Hermione mentions:

> Awful things happen to wizards who meddle with time.

Now, I can imagine what could go wrong logically, for example, their past self could harm their future self perceiving some danger owing to the confusion and chaos, et cetera, et cetera.

But what I was wondering is, if there is a mention, in the book, of any such incidents that might have happened actually in the past to some other wizards?

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer in the link of the other question shared above. However, because of the words in which that question had been framed, it was difficult for me to find it as a question that already had the answer I was looking for..

Answer (score -6):

There is indeed mention in the book of such incidents. In Chapter Twenty-One Hermione tells Harry:

> Professor McGonagall told me what awful things have happened when wizards have meddled with time... Loads of them ended up killing their past or future selves by mistake!”

Apparently, loads of people  have actually killed themselves while messing with time.

Comment: I think the question is asking for specific examples rather than a general restatement of "lots of bad things have happened."

Comment: That's the same line quoted in the question. As Alarion just said while I was typing this, OP is actually asking is if we know of any *specific examples* of (say) wizards who killed their past or future selves. Also, please tell me you didn't re-open what I believe actually *is* a duplicate question, just so you could post such a low-quality answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy [See for yourself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/217528/timeline).

Comment: @Alarion It’s not just a general restatement. It specifies that a significant number of times people have specifically killed themselves, rather then just the general idea that bad things happen to people.

Comment: @F1Krazy I reopened it because it’s a different question (“what bad things have actually happened” vs “why didn’t Voldemort use time travel to fix things?”) and the answer there, while it talks about bad things that happen, contains nothing about whether there is any mention of this in the book. And my answer, which does discuss what is mentioned in the book, does not answer the other question either. As for whether my answer is low quality, that is a separate issue which readers can vote on, or the questioner can clarify that something more specific was meant.

Comment: @Alex The question there wasn't quite "why didn't Voldemort use time travel to (un)fix things", but rather "what non-legal negative consequences are there that would prevent Voldemort from *wanting* to use time travel", a.k.a. "what awful things happen to wizards who mess with time".  But, it's not written in the clearest manner.

Comment: @Chronocidal There is not even any mention of non-legal consequences anywhere in the body of the question. The actual question seems to be about why Voldemort didn't use time travel, and the title alludes to a possible answer, namely that there might be consequences.

Comment: @Alex That question explicitly mentions the Asker's belief that **Harry & friends** didn't use Time Travel because they would be punished by the Ministry of Magic (i.e. "legal consequences").  They ask why Voldemort (who doesn't *care* what the Ministry of Magic think) doesn't use it - which, by a process of induction, means "non-legal consequences", because we've already eliminated the legal ones.

Comment: @Chronocidal That's assuming that the answer is about consequences at all. The answer could just as easily be something completely different, e.g. he didn't have access to a time-turner.